# Как взять из datetimepicker только дату?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

Собственно, как на С++ CLI взять из datatimepicker только дату?

Answer (score 1):

Это должно быть решением:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

Верно?

Answer (score 0):

> Это должно быть решением:
>
> dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
>
> Верно?

Да, верно)) Спасибо. Только на  C++ Это выглядит так:

```
dateTimePicker1->Value.ToShortDateString()
```